# Условный рендеринг (проверка сроки)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Добрый вечер дорогие разработчики
Есть строка вроде

```
"We have of these: variant|label|home"
```

Как сделать условный рендеринг если в строке есть слова "variant", "label", "home"

```
function findWord(word, str) {
 return RegExp('\\b'+ word +'\\b').test(str)
}
```

Пример если найдено функция возращает true иначе false

Comment: если уж регулярки то посмотрите `|` - этот оператор для регулярок, должно помочь

Comment: функция работает! A как сделать всё это через дериктиву v-if ?

Comment: лично я бы не нагружал "разметку" сложной логикой, которая к тому же возможно будет менятся, одной переменной будет достаточно, через вычисляемые поля

Comment: как это реализовать, можете помочь, пожалуйста

Comment: по хорошему конечно нужно было кода побольше в вопросе, но попробую

Comment: ок, но нужно три варианти - для трех разных слов

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myComponent">
    <p v-if="hasKeyword" style="color:red">
      {{message}}
    <p> 
    <input type="text" v-model="message"/>  
  </div>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#myComponent',
      data: {
        message: "your variant here", 
      },
      computed: {
        hasKeyword: function () {
          return  this.message.match(/variant|label|home/g)
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

или по приведенному в вопросе паттерну:

```
this.message.match(/\\b(variant|label|home)\\b/g)
```

Comment: variant|label|home - должен быть по-отдельности каждый

Comment: **должен быть по-отдельности каждый** что это значит? я знал, что плохая идея отвечать на не четко поставленный вопрос... с кодом или объяснением поведения было бы куда легче ответить